# AudioKit - AKOperationGenerator with AKParameters - CPU Issue

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

I need help with sending AKParameters to the AKOperationGenerator. My current solution use a lot of CPU. Is there a better way how to do it?

Here is my example code:

```
import AudioKit

class SynthVoice: AKNode {
    override init() {
        let synth = AKOperationGenerator { p in
            //(1) - 30% CPU
            let osc: AKOperation = AKOperation.squareWave(frequency: p[0], amplitude: p[1], pulseWidth: p[2])

            //(2) - 9% CPU
            //let osc: AKOperation = AKOperation.squareWave(frequency: 440, amplitude: 1, pulseWidth: 0.5)
            return osc
        }
        synth.parameters[0] = 880
        synth.parameters[1] = 1
        synth.parameters[2] = 0.5

        super.init()
        self.avAudioNode = synth.avAudioNode
        synth.start()
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let mixer: AKMixer = AKMixer([SynthVoice(), SynthVoice(), SynthVoice(), SynthVoice(), SynthVoice(), SynthVoice()])
        AudioKit.output = mixer
        AudioKit.start()
    }
}
```

I need 6 voice osc bank with envelope filter for each voice. I did not find any OSC-bank with envelope filter in AudioKit, so I started to write my own via AKOperationGenerator... But the CPU is too high. (About 100% in my project - 6 AKOperationGenerator with PWM square osc and envelope filter and a lot of AKParameters that can be changed via UI)

Thanks for any response.

Comment: Any news here? I am interested in your solution.

Comment: Sorry, I was a little busy, so I started rewriting my implementation yesterday. As Aurelius wrote, it can be done at kernel level. At the moment I had an easy moog low pass filter in PWMOscillator. I am still working on it, but if you want, I can upload my changes somewhere (here?) after it will be finished.

Comment: This would be great, thank you. Maybe I then could get a deeper understanding and start some low level changes by myself as I want to make oscillators syncable (resettable on trigger).

Comment: Here is link to the changed files (it is a work version):
https://github.com/CoufalikJaroslav/AudioKitOscWithFilter
Please see: AKPWMOscillatorBankDSPKernel.hpp and "void run" method. There you can update the logic of filter. (At the moment there is a simple algorithm for testing purpose.)

Answer (score 1):

I'd definitely do this at the DSP Kernel level.  Its C/C++ but its really not too bad.  Use one of the AKOscillatorBank type nodes as your model, but in addition to having an amplitude envelope, put in a filter envelope the same way.  We're releasing an open source synth that does this exact thing in a few months if you can wait.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to do it at the DSP Kernel level.

Comment: I can add you to the AudioKit slack if you like. Its a good way to get personal support from a great team.